# Not able to inline navigation menu

Tags: css

I need assistance in-lining my navigation menu. Currently it displays vertical but I want it to display horizontal to the top right. I'm aware of how to set a more traditional navigation to be horizontal but this has a section in tools where it has 3 sections that are blocks.

[Image of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dlIx.png)

I am making changes to the tools section because there are so many links in that drop down it looks ugly as just a straight drop down so I was trying to make the tools drop down have three blocks.

If it is not something simple that I am missing I may just find a template and rebuild it with that.

```
<style>
li {
list-style-type: none;
display-inline;
}

a {
font-size: 14pt;
color: ;
}

#tools-title {
color: #fff;
}

#container{
width: 45%;
border: 1px solid #000;
padding: 15px;
background-color: #333;
}

#left{
float:left;
width:250px;
border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

#left a{
display: block;
}

#right{
float: right;
width: 250px;
}

#right a{
display: block;
}

#center{
margin:0 auto;
width:250px;
border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

#center a{
display: block;
}
</style>

<body>

<ul class="nav">
<li class="nav-list">

<ul class="nav-resources">
<li class="button-dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle"><img src="resources.png" title="Resources"><span>&#9662;</span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#" target="_blank">Test Task</a>
       <a href="#" target="_blank">QA Training</a>
       <a href="#" target="_blank">App Contact List</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="nav-guides">
<li class="button-dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle">
      <img src="info.png" title="Guides"><span>&#9662;</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="Index/howto.html" target="_blank">Edit Links</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul class="nav-tools">
<li class="button-dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle"><img src="tools.png" title="Tools"><span>&#9662;</span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <div id="container">
            <h3 id="tools-title">Tools Menu</h3>
                <div id="left">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" target="_blank">Application Logger</a>
                        <a href="#" target="_blank">Application Logger Dev</a>
                        <a href="#" target="_blank">Contract Search</a>
                        <a href="#" target="_blank">New Payment Lookup Tool</a>
                        <a href="#" target="_blank">New Payment Lookup Tool Dev</a>
                    </li>
                </div>
                <div id="right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" target="_blank">U-Haul Exception Viewer Dev 2</a>
                        <a href="#" target="_blank">Uhaul.net Exception Viewer</a>
                        <a href="#" target="_blank">WB Management</a>
                        <a href="#" target="_blank">WB Management Dev</a>
                    </li>
                </div>
                <div id="center">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" target="_blank">QA Tool</a>
                        <a href="#" target="_blank">QA Tool Dev</a>
                        <a href="#" target="_blank">U-Haul Exception Viewer</a>
                        <a href="#">U-Haul Exception Viewer Dev</a>
                        <a href="#" target="_blank">U-Haul Exception Viewer 2</a>
                    </li>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul class="nav-about">
<li>
<a href="#" id="myBtn"><img src="about.png" title="About"></a>
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
<!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>QA Application Hub</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Version: 1.0.0</p>
      <p>Last updated: 6/7/17</p>
      <p>Created by: Mark White</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
</ul>




<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>

<ul class="nav-mail">
<li>
    <a href="mailto:someone@email.com"><img src="mailicon.png" style="width: 32px; height: 40px;" title="Send Mail"></a>
</li>
</ul>

</li>
</ul> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your html is little buggy, I have corrected it, so refer that.

To make your **nav bar** in a **horizontal** layout, need to add `dispaly:flex` css property in the `ul`, so that the flexible box will render according to screen size.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
.horizontal-nav{
   display:flex;
   /*float:right;*/  /*If you want all the items on right side */
}

li {
list-style-type: none;
display-inline;
}

a {
font-size: 14pt;
color: ;
}

#tools-title {
color: #fff;
}

#container{
width: 45%;
border: 1px solid #000;
padding: 15px;
background-color: #333;
}

#left{
float:left;
width:250px;
border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

#left a{
display: block;
}

#right{
float: right;
width: 250px;
}

#right a{
display: block;
}

#center{
margin:0 auto;
width:250px;
border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

#center a{
display: block;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav horizontal-nav">
 
 <li class="button-dropdown nav-resources">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle"><img src="resources.png" title="Resources"><span>&#9662;</span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
   <a href="#" target="_blank">Test Task</a>
     <a href="#" target="_blank">QA Training</a>
     <a href="#" target="_blank">App Contact List</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </li>

 <li class="button-dropdown nav-guides">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle">
    <img src="info.png" title="Guides"><span>&#9662;</span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
   <a href="Index/howto.html" target="_blank">Edit Links</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </li>

 <li class="button-dropdown nav-tools">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle"><img src="tools.png" title="Tools"><span>&#9662;</span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <div id="container">
    <h3 id="tools-title">Tools Menu</h3>
    <div id="left">
     <li>
      <a href="#" target="_blank">Application Logger</a>
      <a href="#" target="_blank">Application Logger Dev</a>
      <a href="#" target="_blank">Contract Search</a>
      <a href="#" target="_blank">New Payment Lookup Tool</a>
      <a href="#" target="_blank">New Payment Lookup Tool Dev</a>
     </li>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
     <li>
      <a href="#" target="_blank">U-Haul Exception Viewer Dev 2</a>
      <a href="#" target="_blank">Uhaul.net Exception Viewer</a>
      <a href="#" target="_blank">WB Management</a>
      <a href="#" target="_blank">WB Management Dev</a>
     </li>
    </div>
    <div id="center">
     <li>
      <a href="#" target="_blank">QA Tool</a>
      <a href="#" target="_blank">QA Tool Dev</a>
      <a href="#" target="_blank">U-Haul Exception Viewer</a>
      <a href="#">U-Haul Exception Viewer Dev</a>
      <a href="#" target="_blank">U-Haul Exception Viewer 2</a>
     </li>
    </div>
   </div>
  </ul>
 </li>

 <li class="nav-about">
  <a href="#" id="myBtn"><img src="about.png" title="About"></a>
  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
    
   <div class="modal-header">
     <span class="close">&times;</span>
     <h2>QA Application Hub</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
     <p>Version: 1.0.0</p>
     <p>Last updated: 6/7/17</p>
     <p>Created by: Mark White</p>
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </li>

 <li class="nav-mail">

  <a href="mailto:someone@email.com"><img src="mailicon.png" style="width: 32px; height: 40px;" title="Send Mail"></a>
 </li>


</ul>
```

Comment: That does make it horizontal but the issue with that is it changes the lay out of the drop down for the tools menu.

The end goal is a horizontal menu and the tools drop down menu identical to the image I added in the original question.

Comment: Try to do some css changes for that as whatever you have tried for `tools` dropdown is also not correct.